# asp.net mvc - Simplest way to provide alternate row styling in Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Given the following Razor code:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (Profession profession in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@profession.Name</td>
            <td>@profession.PluralName</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "AddOrEdit", new { Id = profession.ProfessionID })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

What's the simplest way to provide some kind of alternate row styling? (i.e. different styling for odd and even rows.)

I don't seem to be able to add arbitrary C# to declare a `bool` variable which gets flipped each iteration of the `foreach` loop in order to set a classname for the `tr`, for example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'd recommend doing this in straight CSS ([see here for more details](http://davidwalsh.name/css-tables-css3-alternate-row-colors)):

```
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)   { background-color:#fff; }
```

Comment: This is CSS3. **Not every browser supports it.**

Comment: Indeed, and I was hesitant, but the question asked for the 'simplest way', and I believe this is.

Comment: Modern browsers support it. And for legacy browsers there won't be alternating row color => not a big deal. People using legacy browsers are probably already accustomed to seeing differently rendered web sites on the internet.

Comment: Yes, but depends who your audience are. In the industry I am in, most browsers are IE6.

Comment: @Aliostad, it looks very strange to me that an industry that can make an effort to use the latest technology from Microsoft to develop its web applications (ASP.NET MVC 3) is using a 3 generations old web browser. I mean IE6, really, this still exists?

Comment: Welcome to UK NHS. 90% of browsers in UK NHS are IE6. Plan to migration to IE7 in 2012! They had applications built specifically for IE6 which only works in, well, IE6.

Comment: `Plan to migration to IE7 in 2012`. May God have mercy on your souls.

Comment: Well, we have said they need to run the software in chrome frame, so theoretically I could be using `tr:nth-child`. But still favour broadest possible audience.

Comment: @Aliostad - we write web apps for NHS people too. I feel your pain. But this one is just internal, so I can do all the CSS3 I like. Yay!

Comment: I'm giving this one the thumbs up because it works for me and it's the simplest solution.

Comment: Same goes for most of the pharma industry. 95% of our browser traffic is IE6.

Answer (score 11):

JQuery can do that in the client side (and I would probably use client side scripting here rather than server logic).

```
 $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");
```

You can also use just a simple variable to set the css class (almost pseudo-code):

```
@foreach (Profession profession in Model)
{
    @i++;
    <td class="@i%2==0?"even":"odd""> 

}
```

Comment: To avoid complaints from visual studio use brackets, e.g.  <tr class="@(i%2==0? "":"alt")">

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of ways as other proposed. From my point, this wouldn't be the simplest but a bit easier:

```
<tbody>
    @var oddEven = new List { "odd", "even" };
    @var i = 0;
    @foreach (Profession profession in Model)
    {
        <tr style="@oddEven[i++ % 2]">
            <td>@profession.Name</td>
            <td>@profession.PluralName</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "AddOrEdit", new { Id = profession.ProfessionID })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apologies that this is a slightly obtuse answer as you're already doing the mark-up, but as your table looks pretty standard you could switch to using the Mvc Web Grid Helper. It's a neat tool for tables like this. I think your code would be slightly shorter / simpler for this particular table, and the actual implementation of the alternating row style would be *very* simple:

```
alternatingRowStyle: "alternateRow"
```

More info on [this asp.net blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/02/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid-part-2.aspx).

Comment: I like the idea of this control but it would take quite a lot more work than some of the other solutions. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MVC Razor utilizing the @helper function is the simplest, cleanest and best approach.

In the App_Code folder of your project add new item or modify your existing CustomeHelpers.cshtml file with the following code:

```
@helper AlternateBackground(string color, Int32 iViewBagCount) {
    if (iViewBagCount == null) { iViewBagCount = 0; }
    <text>style="background-color:@(iViewBagCount % 2 == 1 ? color : "none")"</text>
    iViewBagCount++;
}
```

Then on your view, inside your foreach loop, replace the tablerow code with what's shown below:

```
<tr @CustomHelpers.AlternateBackground("#ECEDEE", ViewBag.count)>
```

or

```
<tr @CustomHelpers.AlternateBackground("Red", Model.Count())>
```

Whichever is appropriate for your foreach loop

This way you only have to add the @Helper function once and it propagates throughout your application and it can be called on each view as needed by referencing the @CustomHelpers function. Create as many helpers as you need and call them with the @CustomeHelpers.NameOfYourFunction() and go from there.

Simple and effective...